# How to gracefully restart worker nodes of ESB Cluster?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Sometimes we have requirement to stop/restart worker nodes one by one for patches or extention but don't want to interrupt any service requests working at as-is runtime. The graceful restart mode in manager console can be found, but it seems like don't apply to worker node. Does WSO2 work node support graceful restart or stop?

Comment: you can  press Ctrl+C in the command window which will be a graceful stop

Comment: Generally, the worker nodes are working with (nohup) background mode in Linux/Unix environment, you can't stop them with Ctrl+C command.

Answer (score 0):

if the worker node has been started using nohup using nohup sh wso2server.sh -DworkerNode=true & then you may try sh wso2server.sh restart to gracefully restart the worker node.

Secondly, generally there should be more than 1 worker node in a cluster, as a result we should be able to restart the nodes via sh wso2server.sh restart without any issue.

regards,shavantha